# Comparing the sums in different directions of a magic square in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im rather new to java and have just started learning how to use 2d arrays. What I am trying to do is compare my different sums from rows and columns and the different diagonals to determine where the array is a true magic square. However, Right now, all I can do is print out my arrays. I keep getting the error that it cant find the variable I am trying to put in the parameters for colSUm and rowSum. Because of this, im not sure if my logic for sums is actually correct.

```
public class MagicSquare
{
    private int[][] grid;              

    public MagicSquare(int[][] g)     
    {     
        grid=g;
    } 

    /** 
    * find the sum of a given row     
    */    
    public int rowSum(int row)     
    {     
        int sum;
        for (row=0; row < grid.length; row++)
        {
             sum = 0;
             for ( int col=0; col < grid[row].length; col++)
             {
                 sum = sum + grid[row][col];
             }
        }
        return sum;
    }      

    /**     
    * find the sum of a given column     
    */   
    public int colSum(int col)     
    {  
       int sum;
       for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) 
       {
           sum = 0;
           for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) 
           {
               sum += grid[j][i];
           }
       }
       return sum;
    }      

    /**     
    * returns the sum in the "up" diagonal (from the lower left to the upper right) 
    */   
    public int upDiagSum() 
    {     
        int totalup = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
        {    
            totalup += grid[row][row];
        }    
        return totalup;    
    }      

 /** 
    * determines if the sum all rows, columns, and main diagonals are equal     
    */    
    public boolean isMagicSquare()    
    {  
        boolean isMagicSquare = false;
        while(!isMagicSquare)
        {
            if (downDiagSum()!=upDiagSum() && rowSum(row) != colSum(i))
            return false;
            else
            return true;
        }
        return isMagicSquare;
    }
```

I didn't include the downDiag method in here because I did want to get repetitive. These are the 4 most important methods of my code.

Comment: in the rowSum and colSum methods you need only the inner loop

Comment: now im getting the error "method rowSum in class MagicSquare cannot be applied to given types; required int; found no arguments; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length" in my isMagicSquare() method. I tried adding int rows and int col into the parameters, but that didnt work.

Comment: fix the syntax errors yourself

Comment: Thats what I've been trying to do for the past hour. Im not sure what exactly Im doing wrong with that. Can you at least tell me if what I was trying to put in my parameters was even close to right?

Comment: start with defining the downDiagSum function and the variables row and i in the isMagicSquare method

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what you are trying to do in the isMagicSquare function.This is the most straight forward logic I can think of

```
public class MagicSquare
{
    private int[][] grid;

    public MagicSquare(int[][] g)
    {
        grid = g;
    }

    /**
     * find the sum of a given row
     */
    public int rowSum(int row)
    {
        int sum;
        sum = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < grid.length; col++)
        {
            sum = sum + grid[row][col];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * find the sum of a given column
     */
    public int colSum(int col)
    {
        int sum;
        sum = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
        {
            sum += grid[row][col];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * returns the sum in the "up" diagonal (from the lower left to the upper
     * right)
     */
    public int upDiagSum()
    {
        int totalup = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
        {
            totalup += grid[grid.length - row - 1][row];
        }
        return totalup;
    }

    public int downDiagSum()
    {
        int totalup = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
        {
            totalup += grid[row][row];
        }
        return totalup;
    }

    /**
     * determines if the sum all rows, columns, and main diagonals are equal
     */
    public boolean isMagicSquare()
    {
        boolean isMagicSquare = true;
        int upDiagSum = upDiagSum();
        int downDiagSum = downDiagSum();
        if (upDiagSum == downDiagSum)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
            {
                if (colSum(i) == upDiagSum)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    isMagicSquare = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isMagicSquare)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
                {
                    if (rowSum(i) == upDiagSum)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isMagicSquare = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isMagicSquare = false;
        }
        return isMagicSquare;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[][] g = { { 8, 1, 6 }, { 3, 5, 7 }, { 4, 9, 2 } };
        MagicSquare ms = new MagicSquare(g);
        System.out.println(ms.isMagicSquare());
    }
}
```

CHANGES:

1.Both the rowSum and colSum functions now only work on the particular row or column as opposed to iterating through both dimensions.

2.As for the logic of checking isMagicSquare, first check if the diagonals are equal, and if they are compare the sum of every row and column to either diagonal and on first fail, exit with false value, and on no fail exit with true value.

Comment: Please, explain what you have done, and remove the similar methods, this will be more readable ;)

Comment: @AxelH I have added some explanation...and there are no similar methods really, there are minor differences and I'am trying to maintain the OP's original structure...any other feedback is welcome...I don't normally answer such questions...don't even know if I should be

Comment: If you have change a lot, then, this should probably not be answered with code ;) I always feared that the OP just copy paste without searching why this works.

Comment: That actually cleared up a lot of my confusion. Thank you. It is actually very helpful to see a visual representation of what you are saying. And that is basically what I was trying to accomplish in terms of my magic square. I am currently very frustrated by 2d arrays, as I do not completely understand some of the more complex parts of them. Such as what is happening when you code totalup += grid[grid.length-row-1][row]. Do you have any suggestions for reading or a video that would help me improve my understanding of 2d arrays?

Comment: @AxelH haha dont worry about it. Im just trying to learn how to use 2d arrays. This was a recommended activity. I wont copy and paste it. Im more looking to understand how this works. Seeing his code in the format I was trying to use will help me examine the logic, so I can improve later on. I will also try to make adjustments so that my code will not end up exactly like his.

Comment: @DavidVach totalup += grid[grid.length-row-1][row]; apart from the syntax it really has nothing to do with arrays. my suggestion run through the loop manually ;substitute the value for each variable and see exactly what happens; this sample code is more about logic that about any concept and it might the first that you are missing